# NGRX forms - how to deal with multiple, similar forms?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

in my app I am using ngrx forms ([LINK](https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms)).

There are 4 different forms about transport tickets (plane, train, bus, ship). They are similar to each other (for example start/end date, start/end place) ,but some fields about details are different (for example plane has luggage limit)

```
export interface FormOffer {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    description: string;
    startDate: string
    endDate: string
    information: PlaneInformation | TrainInformation | BusInformation |  ShipInformation;
}
```

**I am not sure which approach will be better:**

1. Create 4 reducers, one per each form and store it in separate modules ?
   Each module has forFeature:

   ```
   StoreModule.forFeature('planeForm', reducer)
   ```

   (I did that way)
2. Avoid repeating some part of code and somehow use shared reducer? But I have no idea how to deal with that

My **reducer for plane** looks more or less like this. It will be similar for other transport types:

```
export const validateAndUpdateForm = updateGroup<FormOffer>({
    title: validate(required),
    startDate: validate(required),
    endDate: validate(required),
    information: updateGroup<PlaneInformation>({
        numberOfTickets: validate(required),
        flightNumber: validate(required),
        airline: validate(required),
        ticketClass: validate(required)
    })
});
const reducers = combineReducers<State['planeForm'], any>({
    formState(s = INITIAL_STATE, a: Action) {
        return validateAndUpdateForm(formGroupReducer(s, a));
    }
})
```